# How to prepend a value before xarray.DataArray.diff?

Tags: python, python-xarray

Given a xarray.DataArray with area values ('Af') along date and depth dimensions: `xarray.DataArray 'Af' (time: 366, z: 20)` , how to I get the difference between each area across the depth dimension for each date with the same length as 'area' and the first difference being equal to the first indexed 'area'?

So something like:

area_1 = Af_1

area_2 = Af_1 - Af_2

...

area_i = Af_i - Af_(i-1)

If it was in numpy, I could have used `np.diff(array, prepend=array[0])`, but the prepend option is not available in xarray. Is there any method to imitate `np.diff(array, prepend=0)` in xarray?

I am new to xarray (and coding in general), so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do the following:

1. Compute the differences of the areas along the z-dimension. This will necessarily result in a coordinate that is shorter than before.
2. Then you want to prepend the areas at the first depth to get an array of the same length.

You can us xarray's `diff` method to do the first step and use `concat` to do the second step.

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# Create a dummy dataset
da = xr.DataArray(
    data=np.random.rand(3, 4),
    dims=("time", "z"),
    name="area",
    coords={"time": np.arange(3), "z": np.arange(4)},
)

# Compute the differences
differences = da.diff(dim="z", label="upper")
# Concatenate the differences with the areas at the first depth
xr.concat([da.isel(z=0), differences], dim="z")
```

I think that this is the easiest way, because you can take advantage of xarray's labeled dimensions.
However, you can actually use any numpy function on a xarray DataArray. So you could use `np.diff` as well. However, you will end up with an unlabeled numpy array, so you would have to readd dimensions and coordinates.
The easiest way to do so is the `copy` method using the `data` argument. It will create an array with the same structure as the original one (same dims and coords) but with different data:

```py
# Compute diffs with numpy and write the results back into a DataArray
da.copy(data=np.diff(da, axis=da.get_axis_num("z"), prepend=0))
```